# Can't filter user in wso2 IS with SCIM

Tags: authentication, scim, wso2-identity-server

I tried to filter user or get user detail with the following link :

```
curl -v -k -X GET --user admin:admin --header "Content-Type:application/json" https://localhost:9443/wso2/scim/Users?filter=userName%20Eq%20”admin"
```

and

```
curl -v -k --user hasinitg:hasinitg https://localhost:9443/wso2/scim/Users/me
```

The link is introduced in the document :

```
https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/SCIM+APIs
```

But I can't get any info.
The system informed me that :

```
{"Errors":[{"code":"400","description":"Given filter operation is not supported."}]}
```

I tried with the below code in java but the result is the same :

```
//String url = "https://localhost:9443/wso2/scim/Users?filterEqadmin";
    String url = "https://localhost:9443/wso2/scim/Users/me";
    BasicCookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();

    UsernamePasswordCredentials credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials("admin", "admin");

    SSLContextBuilder builder = new SSLContextBuilder();
    builder.loadTrustMaterial(null, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy());
    SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(builder.build());
    CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClientBuilder.create().setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf)
            .setDefaultCookieStore(cookieStore).build();

    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);
    get.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    get.addHeader("charset", "UTF-8");
    get.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");


    Header header = new BasicScheme().authenticate(credentials, get);
    get.addHeader(header);

    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(get);
    System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + response);

    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
    String line = "";
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        result.append(line);
    }
    System.out.println(result);
```

Error:

```
Response Code : HttpResponseProxy{HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request [Cache-Control: private, Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 08:00:00 ICT, Date: Wed, 14 Sep 2016 10:48:46 GMT, Content-Type: application/json, Content-Length: 84, Connection: close, Server: WSO2 Carbon Server] ResponseEntityProxy{[Content-Type: application/json,Content-Length: 84,Chunked: false]}}
```

{"Errors":[{"code":"400","description":"Given filter operation is not supported."}]}

I don't now what is need to config in WSO2 IS server ?
Could y please help me in this case ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a user name thusitha and then I executed the following query

```
curl -v -k -X GET --user admin:admin --header "Content-Type:application/json" https://localhost:9443/wso2/scim/Users\?filter\=userName+Eq+%22thusitha%22
```

I get the results correctly

```
{"schemas":["urn:scim:schemas:core:1.0"],"totalResults":1,"Resources":[{"id":"486ebfb2-0b39-45a8-b963-02ae27dbd1dc","userName":"thusitha","meta":{"lastModified":"2016-09-15T11:26:09","created":"2016-09-15T11:26:09"}}]}%
```

Can you create a new user and try the above query by changing the name?

Comment: Can y get user info by curl link : 
curl -v -k --user hasinitg:hasinitg https://localhost:9443/wso2/scim/Users/me

Answer (score 0):

/me endpoint was broken in IS 5.1.0, it is a known [issue](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-4329).
This was fixed in latest version 5.2.0.

Other filtering operation is not working since you are using " character without encoding. Try encoding that and send, it should work.